The number of ways in which $7$ different red roses $4$ different blue roses and $5$ alike green roses can form a garland

The number of ways in which $7$ different red roses $4$ different blue roses and $5$ alike green roses can form a garland,is/are (Do not distinguish clockwise and anticlockwise circuular permutation)

My solution: Total number of objects $16$ so in circular permutation of these objects is $15!$ but of these 5 alike and clockwise and anticlockwise is same so answer must be $\dfrac{15!}{5!\cdot2!}$
Is my approach correct?

Looks fine; you can also do these as linear permutations and then anneal the ends and just divide out the circular positions at the end if that's easier to think about.

@RobinSparrow can you give solution in answer section? if possible

Sure, added it.

By a different approach I am arriving at the same answer.
Number of ways to arrange $7$ different red roses and the $4$ different blue roses in a circle will be $(7+4-1)!=10!$
Now, we put the $5$ identical green roses in the $11$ gaps amongst the red roses and the blue roses which is same as the number of non-negative integral solutions to the equation $$x_1+x_2+...+x_{11}=5$$ i.e. in $\binom{5+11-1}{11-1}=\binom{15}{10}$ ways.
So the number of ways will be equal to $$(10)!\binom{15}{10}=\frac{15!}{5!}$$
But since the garland can be viewed from two sides in other words counting clockwise and anti-clockwise arrangements to be the same the required number of arrangements is finally equal to $$\frac{15!}{5!2!}$$

Take the situation linearly at first. You have $11$ distinct items and $5$ like items, which have $\frac{16!}{5!}$ permutations. We disallow left/right symmetry, which means dividing by $2$, for $\frac{16!}{5!2}$ permutations. Then we arrange in a circle with $16$ positions, which means we create $16$-fold rotational symmetry that must be removed, so $\frac{16!}{5!2}\frac{1}{16}=\frac{15!}{5!2}$.

It's kind of overkill to use Burnside's Lemma here, but ...
Ignoring the symmetries, there are $16!/5!$ ways to assign the flowers to garland positions.
None of the $32$ garland symmetries except the identity fixes any assignments, and the identity fixes all of them, so by Burnside's Lemma, the number of distinct orbits is  ($16!/5! + 0 + ... + 0)/32 $
